# How to handle signs in java?

Tags: java

I have a command line with different parameters (strings and an int value).

The problem is that i have both spaces and = characters in this input string, which Java recognizes as separators.
Now i wonder how to parse this into my program.

I look for a possibility to make it as simple as possible. The parameter values must also be passed to various subroutines. So I'm looking for a way to easily access the parameters to pass them to subroutines and at the same time control that each command line contains these parameters (and that they actually contain valid value).

Maybe someone could give me a hint how to do this the most "correct" way.

Comment: Such suggestions are a bit out of scope for Stack Overflow, but I suggest you look into a library that would do that for you, like [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)

Comment: @Mureinik that's what I was thinking too, but Apache Commons CLI and many other open-source CLI parsers are designed to deal with POSIX-like options and positional parameters, which is a different CLI syntax scheme to what the OP has, which is position-independent named parameters. I would have thought collecting these into a HashMap is probably good enough.

Comment: Thank you both. @DodgyCodeException could you give me a tip how I can collect them into a hashmap, I mean, how I can specify what is a parameter and what is a value? That would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> cliParams = new HashMap<>();

        // Full set of required parameters
        cliParams.put("t", null);
        cliParams.put("vo", null);
        cliParams.put("q", null);

        for (String arg : args) {
            String[] nameAndValue = arg.split("=", 2);
            if (nameAndValue.length != 2)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameter syntax: " + arg);

            String name = nameAndValue[0];
            String value = nameAndValue[1];
            if (cliParams.replace(name, value) != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter given more than once: " + arg);
        }

        cliParams.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (v == null) 
                throw new IllegalStateException("Required parameter missing: " + k);
        });

        int q = Integer.parseInt(cliParams.get("q"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really helpful. Just a quick question concerning your code. Should I also catch the Exceptions in the main?

Comment: You don't have to catch exceptions in main. They will be reported to the console (just as if you had caught and done printStackTrace() yourself). You only have to catch them if you want to do something special with the exceptions, e.g. if you have some recovery plans.